# Why does my mouse cursor stick as the default arrow instead of a text selector?

Tags: macos, mouse, text-editor

I use NetBeans, and when I activate other applications or windows then return to NetBeans, the cursor no longer changes to the text selection cursor, but instead it remains as the default mouse icon. I can solve the problem by hovering over the application toolbar, then go back to the editor area.

I have this problem in another IDE, phpstorm, it also happens occasionally in Chrome. TextMate and TextEdit do not have this problem.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it so I don't have to keep moving the cursor outside of the editor constantly?

For further explanation, please pay attention to the mouse cursor in [a video I made showing the problem](http://www.screenr.com/nAns).

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the NetBeans source code. I'm not an expert on Java GUIs, but there should be a `setCursor()` function you can put into `onHover` or something like that. Check the documentation of the GUI toolkit NetBeans uses.

(@tubedogg, Chrome doesn't use a native GUI. Although it tries its best to use the OS look, the title bar is custom, which you can't do with Apple's native GUI toolkit.)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem in Snow Leopard with the cursor not changing from a beach ball (a frozen beach ball, not a spinning one) to a normal cursor. What I’ve done to fix this is mouseover the dock resizing point (see picture below).
Hope this helps!

[image: dockresizing point]

Comment: I've tried, but it didnt unfortunately :(

Comment: He already has a workaround, that's to move it into the Application's toolbar. Having a workaround is not the point of the question, he wants a fix.

Comment: @daviesgeek Your image seems to have disappeared from wherever it's hosted. Do you still have a copy you can move somewhere new?

Comment: @CajunLuke There you go!

Comment: @daviesgeek Thanks. I just happened to see it was missing and I figured you'd be around to fix it.

Comment: @CajunLuke Yah. It was odd. I didn't actually do anything. I clicked "edit" and loaded the URL and the picture just suddenly appeared. It was odd...

Comment: @daviesgeek The server must have been waiting on activity or something. I wondered how you'd fixed it without editing the question.

Comment: I have the same problem. I also made a video of the behaviour. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cmj33QVYFY0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Also happening here. Weird that Apple has never fixed this.

Comment: Pretty big assumption that it's Apple somehow causing this, given that it doesn't happen in some applications. I'm guessing it depends on something in how the application is programmed. I was originally thinking non-native apps (since NetBeans is a Java app), although Chrome is definitely a native app.